# Cython: Is it possible to use operator -> overload in Cython

Tags: syntax, operator-overloading, cython, member

I have a chain of shared_ptr property access, it is in C++ very simple:

```
// All foo, bar, abc, xyz are shared_ptr
foo->bar->abc->xyz
```

But there's no arrow '->' in Cython and there's only dot '.', and the member access above is this way:

```
foo.get().bar.get().abc.get().xyz
```

Is it possible to use operator overload '->' in Cython?
This operator overload is already defined in shared_ptr in C++'s  header but can't be used in Cython, error:

```
# Example:
from libc.stdio cimport printf

printf("%s start time: %f, finish time: %f\n",s.c_str(),
       veh->start_time, veh.get().finish_time)

# Error:
Expected ')', found '->'
```

Comment: No it isn't. You could also use `cython.operators.dereference` (although that doesn't really simplify it)

Comment: my work-around is currently making operator () overload so it's neat: foo().bar().abc().xyz(). But maybe cython should support arrow, more convenient to use sometimes

Comment: There might be issues adding new syntax. It'll kind of conflict with the existing `->` return type annotation syntax and it's hard to know if Python will add similar syntax in future. There's possibly better ways of expressing it, but probably not the C++ way.